# Characterise all subgroups of $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb F_{p^n})$

Tags: finite-groups, finite-fields

The title pretty much explains everything. Is it possible to give an easy characterisation of all subgroups of $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb F_{p^n})$?